# CakePhp where() condition is not working on HasMany relation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.8

I have to table

```
1. Products
2. VendorsInventories
```

NB: Product may contain more than one VendorsInventories.

In Model/Table/VendorsInventories

```
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('vendors_inventories');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Products', [
            'foreignKey' => 'products_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

And in: Model/Table/ProductsTable.php

```
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('products');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->hasMany('VendorsInventories',[
            'foreignKey' => 'products_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

in query:

```
$products=$this->Products->find('all')->contain(['VendorsInventories']);
```

and the result is:

[image: Response ofcode]

***My main question is: How to seletct rows which contain Relation data.
N.B: belongsTo() is working fine, i have problem with hasToMany()***

Answer (score 1):

Check the [CakePHP Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/intro/conventions.html#database-conventions)

> Foreign keys in hasMany, belongsTo/hasOne relationships are recognized
>   by default as the (singular) name of the related table followed by
>   `_id`. So if Users hasMany `Articles`, the `articles` table will refer to the `users` table via a `user_id` foreign key. For a table like
>   `article_categories` whose name contains multiple words, the foreign key
>   would be `article_category_id`.

So, change

```
'foreignKey' => 'products_id',
```

to

```
'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
```